# Get directory path from JFileChooser into photo viewer

Tags: java, image, directory, jfilechooser

i've got a little problem with getting photos directory into the image viewer. I use JFileChooser, which user can choose only a directory. Can you tell me what to set in code instead of "/obrazy/obrazysm" ?

```
JFileChooser wybierz = new JFileChooser();

public String[] getImages() {
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/obrazy/obrazysm").getFile());
    String[] imagesList = file.list();
    return imagesList;
}

public void fileChooser(){
    wybierz.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    wybierz.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    int v = wybierz.showOpenDialog(null);
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: im making a photo viewer in JFrame, with buttons previous, next and i need to get images from directory selected by user in filechooser

Comment: `fileChooser()` is never called. Also, you need to retrieved the selected value:

Answer (score 0):

`fileChooser()` is never called. Also, you need to retrieve the selected value.
Try this:

```
JFileChooser wybierz = new JFileChooser();

public String[] getImages() {
    File file = fileChooser();  
    String[] imagesList = file.list();
    return imagesList;
}

public File fileChooser() {
   File selectedDirectory = null;
   wybierz.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
   wybierz.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

   //result of select files (yes/no/cancel)
   int ync = wybierz.showOpenDialog(null);

   //if 'ok' has been pressed
   if (ync == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedDirectory = wybierz.getSelectedFile();            
   }
   return selectedDirectory;
}
```